# jQuery Smooth Div Scroll WP - How to start again autoscroll when mouse not over image?

Tags: wordpress, html, scroll, alignment

Please I need your help:
I'm using Smooth Div Scroll with wordpress

- Is there a way to "stop the autoscrolling when mouse over", "start autoscrolling when mouse not over"?
  Right now, autoscrolling works but when I put my mouse over, it stops and does not start again.

I saw it working on this website http://broadcast-architech.com/ however there's no arrow and I would like to keep them, along with the mouse scroll.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll find it much easier to get help if you include the relevant code in your question. Also you need to indicate what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The code could look something like this:

```
// Initialization
var myScroller = $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
    autoScrollingMode: 'onStart',
    autoScrollingDirection: 'endlessLoopLeft'
});

myScroller.on('mouseenter', function(){
    myScroller.smoothDivScroll("stopAutoScrolling");
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    myScroller.smoothDivScroll("startAutoScrolling");
});
```

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/tkahn/3McmN/2/